# Why does the innerText method not working on a button?

Tags: javascript, function

I made a basic quiz that shows 2 questions. When I wait for 10 seconds, the code runs. The issue I have is that when I finishes the quiz, I want the text of the button to change to "Take The Quiz Again". But it is not doing it. I know that innerText is the only method for it. There is no error in console, so I think I don't have any syntax errors in my code.

Here is my JavaScript, CSS, and HTML code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("d").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var score = 0;
    var q1 = prompt("What is 1+1?");
    if (q1 == 2) {
      alert("correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q1 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    var q2 = prompt("What is 2+2?");
    if (q2 == 4) {
      alert("Correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q2 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      "You got " + score + " out of 2";
    if (score > 1) {
      alert("Great Job");
    }
    document.getElementById("d").style.display = "none";
  }, 10000);
  if (q2) {
    document.getElementById("button").innerText =
      "Take The Quiz Again";
  }
}
```

```css
#d {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" Id="button">
Start Quiz
</button>
  <p Id="d">
    Please wait while the system load the quiz. Give a few seconds...
  </p>
  <p Id="demo">
  </p>
</body>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your console for errors. `q2` is local to the `setTimeout` callback function, you can't access it outside. Also, the function doesn't wait for the timeout, so `if(q2)` is executed before you answer any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `q2` is local to the callback function of `setTimeout()`, so `if (q2)` is trying to read an undefined variable, and the condition fails.

And even if you declared the variable outside the callback function, it still wouldn't work. The `if` statement is executed immediately, not after the user has answered the questions.

You don't need that `if` statement. Just put the button change at the end of the function that asks all the quiz questions.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("d").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var score = 0;
    var q1 = prompt("What is 1+1?");
    if (q1 == 2) {
      alert("correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q1 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    var q2 = prompt("What is 2+2?");
    if (q2 == 4) {
      alert("Correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q2 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      "You got " + score + " out of 2";
    if (score > 1) {
      alert("Great Job");
    }
    document.getElementById("d").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("button").innerText =
      "Take The Quiz Again";
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
#d {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" Id="button">
Start Quiz
</button>
  <p Id="d">
    Please wait while the system load the quiz. Give a few seconds...
  </p>
  <p Id="demo">
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: According to w3schools.com, JavaScript code is excuted in order for which the code is written. I don't understand why the if statement is excuted imidiately.

Comment: Code in functions are not executed until the function is called. `setTimeout()` delays calling the function, but it doesn't wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never execute this code:

```
if (q2) {
    document.getElementById("button").innerText =
      "Take The Quiz Again";
  }
```

q2 is always undefined outside of the callback function you pass to `setTimeout`.

Try like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("d").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var score = 0;
    var q1 = prompt("What is 1+1?");
    if (q1 == 2) {
      alert("correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q1 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    var q2 = prompt("What is 2+2?");
    if (q2 == 4) {
      alert("Correct");
      score++;
    } else if (q2 == "") {
      alert("Please enter something");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      "You got " + score + " out of 2";
    if (score > 1) {
      alert("Great Job");
    }
    document.getElementById("d").style.display = "none";

    if (q2) {
       document.getElementById("button").innerText =
          "Take The Quiz Again";
    }
 }, 10000);
  
}
```

```css
#d {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" Id="button">
Start Quiz
</button>
  <p Id="d">
    Please wait while the system load the quiz. Give a few seconds...
  </p>
  <p Id="demo">
  </p>
</body>
```